# EF Core multiple custom foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I am using  code first with EF Core.

I have these two entities :

```
public class BOM
{
    [Key]
    public Guid IdBOM { get; set; }
    public Guid IdArticleCompound { get; set; }
    public Article ArticleCompound { get; set; }
    public Guid IdArticleComponent { get; set; }
    public Article ArticleComponent { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public Guid IdArticle { get; set; } 
    ##############
    #other fields#
    ##############
    public ICollection<BOM> BOMComponents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BOM> BOMCompounds { get; set; }
}
```

fluent API :

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<BOM>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.IdBOM).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.HasOne(m => m.ArticleCompound).WithMany(t => t.BOMCompounds).HasForeignKey(m => m.IdArticleCompound).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            entity.HasOne(m => m.ArticleComponent).WithMany(m => m.BOMComponents).HasForeignKey(m => m.IdArticleComponent).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });
```

An article can have multiple BOM rows where he is the component and an article can be in multiple BOM rows as a compounds.

when i update my database it creates the 2 columns(ArticleCompound, ArticleComponent) in addition to the id columns(IdArticleCompound, IdArticleComponent)
I tried many things to map those 2 customs foreign keys but i can't make it work. I just want the id columns to be in my database..

If someone can help me figuring it out, would be great !
thanks for the help.

Comment: You will have to use Fluent API in order to declare the relational part of the DB. Here is the MSDN documentation on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#foreign-key

As you can see their example it is quite similar to your entities.

Comment: I already use fluent API for others foreign keys but here it's not working. (i've edited my question with the fluent API that i use)

Comment: The model and configuration look ok. What really is not working? What do you mean by "it creates 2 fields"? Do you mean table columns? There is no way EF to create columns for navigation properties.

Comment: I want it to create only field "IdArticleCompound " and "IdArticleComponent" in this database, but it creates these two field and in addition the fields "ArticleCompound" and "ArticleComponent"

Comment: _it creates the 2 fields(ArticleCompound, ArticleComponent) in addition to the "foreignKeys" (IdArticleCompound, IdArticleComponent)_

Comment: There is no such term "field" in database. Are you saying it creates 2 **columns** in the `BOM` database table? And what is the **type** of these columns? Can we see the generated migration?

Comment: yeah sorry by fields i mean columns

Comment: It creates navigation properties as column? Yes, please provide code for those two types and even the table scheme would be good.

Comment: Well since @IvanStoev said that the model and configuration looked good, i've searched if it was a migration problem and the problem was coming from there.. i had to remove/add then update database to get the result i expected. Thanks for the help anyway !